# Python function overload with mypy

Tags: python, overloading, mypy

I have recently started adding type definitions to my Python code and I am stuck at this problem.

Given a `foo.py` file:

```py
from typing import overload


@overload
def foo(a: int) -> int: ...

@overload
def foo(b: float) -> int: ...

def foo(a: int = 0, b: float = 0) -> int:
    # implementation not relevant
    return 42
```

When I run `mypy` I get the following error:

```sh
$ mypy foo.py
foo.py:10: error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2  [misc]
```

I cannot understand where the error is.

In Java I can do that:

```java
interface IFoo {
        int foo(int a);
        int foo(float b);
}

public class Foo implements IFoo {
        public int foo(int a) {
                return this.foo(a, 0f);
        }

        public int foo(float b) {
                return this.foo(0, b);
        }

        private int foo(int a, float b) {
                // implementation not relevant
                return 42;
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) {
                Foo obj = new Foo();
                System.out.println(obj.foo(1));
                System.out.println(obj.foo(1f));
                System.out.println(obj.foo(1, 1f));
        }
}
```

Can anybody explain me what I am doing wrong in the Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is that when one call your function with an argument:

```
foo(x)
```

that `x` is always for the `a` argument, thank to this signature:

```
def foo(a: int) -> int: ...
```

and your:

```
def foo(b: float) -> int: ...
```

is never matched.

Comment: I know in Python I can explicitely use foo(a=x) or foo(b=x), but my issue is that I get the error on the definition of foo(), not on its usage.

Comment: Mypy try to guess all possible uses of code also if not used at all.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. To avoid that I had to mandate the use of keyword arguments (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) to explicitly avoid the case where foo(x).

Comment: Yes, often overload variants in typeshed stubs have an `...,*,...` form.